# Better results with OpenSearch on Sharepoint 2013 (online)

Tags: search, sharepoint-online, search-results

We are wanting to change out site search to use a search engine instead.
We got bing.com working nice with the string:

```
http://www.bing.com/search?q={searchTerms}+site%3Amysite.com&format=rss
```

Now since we are using SharePoint Online we assume the reason that we don't get our ideal search results from Bing is because the server are located in a different country than us and out clients using SharePoint.
Is there anything we can do in order to adjust the query to make it know we are from XXXX country?

We tried using the 'market' parameter in the bing URL but that didnt seem to do much change.

Also alternative are we able to use Google for this search instead? and if so how?

Comment: Is this on a Public SharePoint site in SPO?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Yes, public facing site on SPO

Comment: I haven't worked with SPO Public sites.